# replace the array values with other value getting from database query

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

We are try to fetch the delivery date from the db but its dropdown with the following options.

```
$this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => '',
                    'label' => 'Select Preferred Delivery Time'
            );
            $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => '10am-1pm'
            );
            $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => 2,
                    'label' => '2pm-6pm'
            );
            $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => 3,
                    'label' => '7pm-10pm'
            );
```

with this options.
When i fetch it using from the db it gives me the values as 1 or 2 or 3 depending on the option chosen by the user. but i want to replace that values with the label values.
the query i am using for this is

```
$select->joinLeft(array('delivery' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_address')), 'delivery.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and delivery.address_type="shipping"', array('delivery_time' => 'delivery_time'));
```